# Wordpress - Visual Composer Post Grid - выводить сразу

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

В данный момент элемент Post Grid подгружает материалы динамически. Т.е. даже первые 10, которые должны были быть на странице изначально.

Мне нужно, чтобы первые 10 постов шли в исходном коде сразу, а остальные уже по возможности подгружались.

Можно ли это сделать или забить на Visual Composer и писать запрос на чистом Wordpress API, а потом все это оформлять дизайном?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего использовать плагин [Load More](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/).